# Scala - why does :: not change a List?

Tags: list, scala, immutability

I have just written this code for some fun and I have a question why it isn't working out?

```
  val list = List[Int]()

  while (list.length < 20) {  
    Random.nextInt(100) :: list
  }

  println(list)
}
```

Seems like nothing is written to the list, but why is that so? Do I have to make it mutable? And why is here the `::` operator not working properly?

Comment: The code is effectively the same as: `var x = 0; while (x < 20) { x + 1 }` .. and make sure to read the documentation before making accusations :}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `x :: xs` returns a new list, where the first element is `x`, followed by `xs`.

So, to make your code *work*, make list a `var` and re-assign it inside the loop:

```
var list = List[Int]()

while(list.length < 20)
  list = Random.nextInt(100) :: list
```

However, the idiomatic way of doing this in Scala is to not use mutations at all (local mutable state is fine sometimes though). "While" loops can usually be replaced with a recursive function:

```
def go(xs: List[Int]) =
  if (xs.length >= 20) xs
  else go(Random.nextInt(100) :: xs)

go(List())
```

This particular scenario can also be solved using [`List.fill`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$@fill[A](n:Int)(elem:=%3EA):CC[A]) instead

```
val list = List.fill(20)(Random.nextInt(100))
```

Comment: @ArmaGeddon No prob. Take a look at the recursive solution I added. In functional programming, recursive functions are favored over while loops and such.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your fast and gentle help. Yes I will of course take a look at it sir, thank you!