# Immutable Lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, addition, immutability

I am just trying to figure out how immutable things like a List are working, and how I can add things to it?

I am very sorry for asking such dumb questions, but why is here my list always empty when printing it out?

```
var end = false
val list = List()
while (!end) {
  val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
  if (input == "stop" ) end = true
  else input :: list
}

println(list)

}
```

Sorry for my inconvenience and this rather stupid question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala - why does :: not change a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555414/scala-why-does-not-change-a-list)

Comment: @dcastro: Yes you are right! Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am just trying to figure out how immutable things like a List are working, and how I can add things to it?

You can't. That's what *immutable* means, after all. If Latin is not your cup of tea, the English translation of *immutable* is *unchangeable*. It should be clear now, why you can't *change* something that is *unchangeable*.

> I am very sorry for asking such dumb questions, but why is here my list always empty when printing it out?

You create an empty list, and you never change it (because it *cannot* be changed anyway). So, of course it is empty.

What can you *can* do, however, is create a *new* list which is almost exactly like the *old* list, except with a new item prepended to the front. That's what you are doing here:

```
input :: list
```

However, you don't assign this new list anywhere, you don't return it, you completely ignore it.

If you want to actually use your list in any way, you need to remember it somehow. The most obvious solution would be to assign it to a variable:

```
var end = false
var list: List[String] = List() // note: `var` instead of `val`
while (!end) {
  val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
  if (input == "stop" ) end = true
  else list = input :: list // note: assign to `list`
}
println(list)
```

However, that's not very idiomatic. After all, we have now taken an *immutable* list and assigned it to a *mutable* variable … IOW, we have just moved the mutability around.

Instead, we could use a *recursive* solution:

```
def buildListFromInput(list: List[String] = List()): List[String] = {
  val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
  if (input == "stop") list else buildListFromInput(input :: list)
}

println(buildListFromInput())
```

This solution is not only recursive, the recursive call is also in *tail position* (IOW, the method is *tail-recursive*), which means that it will be just as efficient as a `while` loop (in fact, it will be compiled into a `while` loop, or more precisely, into a `GOTO`). The Scala Language Specification guarantees that all implementations of Scala *must* eliminate direct tail-recursion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes my problem was that I wasnt able to find a solution which is adding this input to the list and not stoping to ask for input after the first loop. When I was trying to do it with a function, it worked because I got a return value but I got completely lost when trying to loop the input !

Answer (score 2):

The reason

```
println(list)
```

is only printing out an empty list is because the bit

```
input :: list
```

isn't actually mutating the list itself. It is simply, in this case, very temporarily, creating a list containing the input at the front.

Try

```
println(input :: list)
```

or

```
val newList = input :: list
println(newList)
```

and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In scala List is immutable.

### Then how can I add items to the list?

When you add an item to list a new `List` instance is crated with a item as its head and its tail now contains the previous list.

If you have list of "1,2,3" called `intList` internally it is represented as

> List(3, List(2, List(1, Nil) ) )

If you add an element `4` to this `intList`

> List(4, intList )

Lets call this `newList`

**Note** `intList` still contains `List(3, List(2, List(1, Nil) ) )`.

If you want the `intList` to refer the `newList` You will have to do

```
intList = intList.add(4)
```

### How can I fix my code

Change list from `val` to `var`. Then you can assign resulting List to `list` variable

```
list = input :: list
```

**Source**: Online course on Scala called [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005)

Comment: You must also make list a var for this assigment to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the code in more functional way. Every operation on Immutable data structures return new instance with change. So `::` operator creates new List with `input` on front. You might want to try rewrite this code as tail recursive function as follows.

```
@tailrec
def scanInput(continue: Boolean,acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
  if(!continue) acc
  else scanInput(input != "stop", input :: acc)
}
```

Above code has no mutating state and it suits more Scala functional style.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, for your help! As I see, recursion seems really important in functional programming so I will take a look on how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, I appreciate your help so much from all of you!
I should have taken a closer look at recursion since it seems to be really important like in Scala!
But trough your help I am getting an better idea of how it works!

I just tried to figure out how your solutions are working and created my own:

```
val list = List()

def scanInput(acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
input match {
case "stop" => acc
case _ => scanInput(input :: acc)
 }
}

println(scanInput(list))
```